# C# Compiler Error when name of auto-property and a method is identical within interface definition

Tags: c#, interface

I'd like to specify an interface as follows:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
  int MyMember
  {
    get;
  }

  int MyMember(string parameter);
}
```

But that leads to a compiler error:

> Error  CS0102  The type 'MyInterface' already contains a definition for 'MyMember' MyComponent.Interfaces

So my question is why is this a problem for the compiler.

Comment: You should ask yourself: why do I need this? Obviously if two members do different things then they should have different names. And obviously a your method can´t do the same as your property, or - more precisely - it could, but it shouldn´t (code-duplication is evil).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the names are *equal*. The compiler cannot decide which of the two symbols you are referring to.

Note that you can assign the *method* `MyMember` to a delegate variable:

```
Func<string, int> method = instance.MyMember;
```

Here the compiler could actually know that you mean the method since the property has another signature, but what about that:

```
var somethign = instance.MyMember;
```

There are two many problems when you allow equal names in the same scope. And it's pretty sure that the developer who tries to do this will confuse himself and his co-workers leading to more errors.

So if I had to develop a programming language, I would not allow this.

Comment: Also is very confusing. A class (let's class TestClass) that implements the interface will expose two Members. `MyMember` and `MyMember(string)`. For a consumer of `TestClass` will not be clear which of two to use.